# Android compatibility issues (Api 8, ActionbarSherlock)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to set-up a basic structure for my project, which is supposed to run on API-levels 8 - 16, uses google location services and ActionBarSherlock.

[See my other question for the setup.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710544/configuring-the-right-android-api-level-for-my-project)

I generated a simple activity with Eclipse (Master-Detail-Flow). My project currently has just one Activity and one Fragment. All I did so far is replacing the super classes with their ABS counterparts:

```
public class CouponListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements CouponListFragment.Callbacks {
...
}
```

and

```
public class CouponListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
...
}
```

This is the one and only layout-element I'm using

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="....activity.CouponListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/coupon_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".CouponListActivity" />
```

This **runs fine on an emulator on API 16**, but **fails on another emulator with API 8**.

The problem is that I cannot interpret the stacktrace in any helpful way. My code does not the seem to get touched at all...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

Where can I start looking for the problem? Let me know if I can provide more information.

**Update**: I have the exact same stacktrace if I rule out ABS and simply try to create a List-Activity / -Fragment combination that runs in API 8. [Here is the project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1206138/android/MyTestApp_zip.zip).

Comment: Can you post manifest file too??

Comment: See the linked post - it has minSDK 8 and targetSDK16

Comment: Yes, I did it (updated other thread accordingly).

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem, I believe stacktrace is not complete. Try to add complete stacktrace.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for trying to help me :) This is the full stacktrace as produced by logcat, there's nothing missing, unfortunately.

Comment: I will try an example, and link you to the source.

Comment: If it runs I will send a beer to any part of world you name.

Comment: I wud be back after 30~40min :)

Comment: 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment did not create a view.' - if you write more just create an answer - that should be easier to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing your source code, you are using `simple_list_item_activated_1` resource. Which was new to Android API level 11 So Solution for your problem is.

`onCreate` method should be something like this

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));
 }
```

Since this was new to API Level 11, You will get same error with or without ActionBarSherlock.  If you want to use `simple_list_item_activated_1` then you need to create a local copy of it. Sorry for being late

Comment: Thanks a million, mate. I was just about to find out the same, but being a Android-Newbie I found it incredible hard to get from the stacktrace to the error...

Comment: @jangroth thank you for offering me a beer, but unfortunately i dont drink. Em glad i could help you it took me a while for analyzing code. Thanks again for the offer :)

Comment: Okay, deleting the comment with my mail address then. Pity, would have been good fun to find out how to send a beer / coke to India :)

Comment: @jangroth you are a java ee specialist, so can u please suggest me few good books to learn jsp and jsf??

Comment: THAT is an easy question. For JSF, try "JSF specification by Ed Burns". For JSP you should probably be good with the public available resources at Sun / Oracle